# AWS Lambda javascript keep alive connection to third party API

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am using a lambda function to proxy request to a third party REST API, adding on the lambda side our third party API key, so it is not visible on our front end app.

The AWS documentation about [reusing connections in nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html) mentions the environnement variable `AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED`.

Does anyone know if this is working with [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Answer (score 1):

Using Axios this variable can be used directly on the HTTP(s) agent of with whatever other variable and of course a hardcoded version of true. To do so, create an axios instance hat will be reused across the requests with the httpAgent or in my case httpsAgent using keep alive to true:

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: THIRDPARTY_BASE_URL,
  headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${THIRDPARTY_ACCESS_TOKEN}` },
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
});
```